# Correlative comparative: "The + comparative adjective + noun + clause"

Tags: correlative-constructions

Consider this sentence:

> 1 The more skills you learn, the more opportunity you will have.

As far as I know, "the more" is a comparative adjective here.

Can I also say it in this way:

> 2 The more you learn skills, the more you will have opportunity.

I think here "the more" is not a comparative adjective anymore, rather it is a comparative adverb. If the sentence #2 is grammatical, how it differ from the sentence #1 in terms of the meaning conveyed?

As far as I know, the structure "The more + clause, the more + clause" is a valid structure and there should be no grammatical problem with the sentence #2.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can say it that way.

It's meaning does not change, except that the second example *can* be taken to imply that you are better off learning a greater quantity of separate skills.

Edited as a result of comment by stangdon.

Comment: I have to disagree a bit.  "The more skills you learn" means "*the greater number of* skills you learn".  "The more you learn skills" could mean "the more thoroughly you learn skills".

Comment: @stangdon What about "the more opportunity you will have." and "the more you will have opportunity."? Do they differ in terms of the meaning they convey?

Comment: @alireza: They mostly differ  in that native speakers aren't very likely to say *...the more you will have opportunity* (dated, "literary" phrasing). But actually, I'm sure most of us would pluralize as *...the more **opportunities** you will have* anyway. They all mean the same, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is "the more opportunities you will have" actually the reduced form of "the more opportunities **that** you will have".?? Can I generalize it and say after the structure is actually like this: ""The + comparative adjective + noun + clause" + **("that")** + clause ???

Comment: The relativizer "that" is *always* optional in such contexts. I don't think it's meaningful to say that an utterance that *doesn't* include it is the "reduced form" of the same *with* it. And I should point out that idiomatically, native speakers would *normally* discard the ***first*** "that" in utterances of the general form *The more|less **that** X [verbs], the more|less **that** Y [verbs]*. And we would *almost always* discard the ***second*** "that".

Comment: ...virtually no-one would ever say *The more skills **that** you learn, the more opportunity **that** you will have.*